# How to access variable which is inside subscribe in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular7

I have a problem of accessing a variable which is inside subscribed. Here I am including code and in ngOninit, I have service which returns object and from that object, I can able to get json which I want and then I am trying to store it in a variable and then I am trying to access that variable outside subscribe which I can not able to do it. So how can I use a variable outside subscribe.

```js
ngOnInit() {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.dataService.GetFormById(+id).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
      const temp = response['TemplateJson'];
      var Data = temp;
    })

    initJq();
      var formData = Data

      this.formBuilder = (<any>jQuery('.build-wrap')).formBuilder({ formData });

     // Sample code to handle promise to get for data on page load directly
      this.formBuilder.promise.then(formBuilder => {
        console.log(formBuilder.formData);
      });
  }
```

In this code inside subscribe there are variable Data and in temp i have json so how can i store that Data in formData variable.

Comment: your variable "Data" must be "public", that's, not declare using var, declare as part of the componen and use this.Data. (or you can call to your function initJq INSIDE the subscribe and pass as argument Data. (NOTE: in typescript NOT use var, use "let")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward,

```js
data: any;
ngOnInit() {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    const that = this;
    this.dataService.GetFormById(+id).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
      // const temp = response['TemplateJson'];
      that.data = response['TemplateJson'];
    })

  }
```

Since this is asynchronous `this.data` must check before using if its defined or not, or you can do whatever you want inside the **asynchronous** callback which is inside the subscription block where `data` get initialized.

**Example**

```js
data: any;
ngOnInit() {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    const that = this;
    this.dataService.GetFormById(+id).subscribe(response => {
      // this is an asynchronous callback
      console.log(response);
      // const temp = response['TemplateJson'];
      that.data = response['TemplateJson'];
      that.generateForm();   // calling method after initializing the this.data variable
    })
  }
generateForm() {
    // just copying your question content to give you an idea
    const formData = this.data;
    this.formBuilder = (<any>jQuery('.build-wrap')).formBuilder({ formData });
    this.formBuilder.promise.then(formBuilder => {
    console.log(formBuilder.formData);
  });
}
```

Comment: I can not able to use const data : any; i am getting error class member can not have 'const' keyword.

Comment: undefine this.data

Comment: And as my answer states, you have to check for property value or you have to do what ever you do inside the callback method.

Comment: so do you mean now i can use it this.data outside of subscribe like if i want to store it in variable outside subscribe then how can i do it ?

Comment: You can use it, but you have to check for `undefined` before you use or do it inside the block. I'll update the answer with an example

Comment: if i want to use generateForm() outside subscribe becuase if id is null then i am getting error.

Comment: @RonakDumaniya point of my answer is you have to initialize the `this.data` variable before you use it. Since you are using a subscription you are following a **asynchronous** pattern. I suggest that wrap the _content_ inside the `generateForm` method with `if (this.data) {// content of generateForm }`

Comment: For me it looks like you have not clear idea about **asynchronous** call here. You are using a data service to get a response here. that's where `this.data` is initialized. It takes some time. while its getting data rest of the code is getting executed synchronously. If you use `this.data` rest of the code you have to make sure it is initialized. That's where `if` block comes in. Take a look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39503464/6434407).

Answer (score 0):

2 ways i can think of depending on your code : Just set a global variable and reference it in your subscription:

```
`
data = null; //here
const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
this.dataService.GetFormById(+id).subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response);
  const temp = response['TemplateJson'];
  this.data = temp; //here use it wherever you want using this.data, but check if its null
})

initJq();
  var formData = Data

  this.formBuilder = (<any>jQuery('.build-wrap')).formBuilder({ formData });

 // Sample code to handle promise to get for data on page load directly
  this.formBuilder.promise.then(formBuilder => {
    console.log(formBuilder.formData);
  });
}`
```

Or (since most of the code which requires data from a subscribtion must run async) just use rxjs pipe and pass the data to a tap or any other operator you want:

```
 this.dataService.GetFormById(+id).pipe(
  map(response => {
  console.log(response);
  const temp = response['TemplateJson'];
  const data = temp;
  return data
    }),
  tap((data)=>{ // can be anyother operator and the map above can also be removed 
     //do something
    })).subscribe();
```

Comment: This approch not helpful for me